# Create a dataframe where the columns are existing Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem.
I have made 3 queries to 3 different tables on a database where the data is similar and stores the values on 3 different dataframes.
My question is: Is there any way to make a new data frame where the column is a Dataframe?
Like this image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gsnC.jpg

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: But maybe need `df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1, keys=('df1','df2','df3'))`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what exactly you need but you can try this:-

```
pd.DataFrame([d["col_name"] for d in df])
```

Where df is the dataframe as shown in image, col_name is the column name which you want as a separate dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to jezrael for the answer.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1, keys=('df1','df2','df3'))
```